Can the subjunctive mood be combined with ‘Be to+infinitive’?
I encountered the sentence

After this examination, my advisor suggested that Betty be to find a new teacher.

My friend claims it uses the subjunctive mood with the ‘be to + infinitive’ structure, and his teacher said it’s correct. However, I believe it’s awkward and non-standard English. I’ve searched for information on combining these two structures but found no clear explanation. I also asked on Quora but didn’t receive a detailed answer. Could someone explain whether it’s correct to use the subjunctive mood with ‘be to + infinitive’ in this context? My friend plans to study abroad, so understanding this correctly is crucial for him.

I've never seen such a thing. If it were up to me, I would certainly delete "be to" there.

After this examination, my advisor suggested that Betty 's focus be to find a new teacher.(??)  And it would be [be + to infinitive] not [be to + infinitive].

The text is transcribed wrong, and someone is standing by it like a street hostess near a lamppost. It's a mess and someone and his teacher said something is right because they saw a different version.

Maybe the actual sentence was "..my advisor suggested that she better be finding a new teacher". Either way, this sounds very weird. Maybe it's very old-fashioned English?

Ironically, I think your friend needs to find himself a new teacher.

It sounds like the sort of odd combination of technically grammatical constructions that a non-native speaker who had learnt mainly from grammar books might produce.
Betty is to find a new teacher is both grammatical and idiomatic, if noticeably formal.
The advisor suggested that Betty find a new teacher is also both grammatical and idiomatic.
The original sentence sounds off because it combines two constructions that have a similar but ultimately incompatible meaning. After laborious analysis, it feels like the advisor is saying that Betty is required to be required to do something, which feels strange. Before that analysis, it honestly seemed like whoever had written the sentence had begun writing ‘suggested Betty to find’, noticed is wasn’t idiomatic English, and attempted to recast the sentence, but forgot to remove the original text.
A compounding factor may also be that, on the face of it, this curious sentence seems similar to suggested Betty should find, which is both grammatical and idiomatic. A non-native speaker might mistake the constructions to be interchangeable, or merely have chosen one by accident.

Actually, my friend think that the sentence has the same meaning as “After this examination, my advisor suggested that Betty must find a new teacher”.

@Jonathanlingual This construction could appear with should, must, or a lone subjunctive, with pretty much the same meaning. The issue with the original sentence is that it remains grammatical as a technicality, but is nevertheless so unidiomatic that it sounds ungrammatical - to a native speaker, almost unparseable at a glance. And when it has been parsed, its meaning has been awkwardly doubled up.

@Jonathanlingual The problem is that [suggest + subjunctive] means ‘suggest that (X) should/ought to (do Y)’, while [is/was to + infinitive] roughly means that X either must/has to do Y, or that it is planned/expected/inevitable that X will do Y. Suggesting that X be to do Y then means suggesting that X ought to have to do Y, which is too much modality for English. You can suggest that X ought to do Y, or you can suggest that X has to do Y, but that someone ought to have to do something is just not something that’s used in English.

@Jonathanlingual The reason why the versions with should, must work is that those are auxiliary/modal verbs whose function in English is similar to a subjunctive, hence their being ‘modal’ (= of mood). The construction to be to verb has not been similarly grammaticalized in English.

'Technically grammatical' sounds weasily, I'm afraid. There are areas of divided usage (after Greenbaum and Svartvik) where seasoned Anglophones / English language graduates are divided in their opinions as to whether certain sentences are grammatical/acceptable (now I'm being imprecise). But I'd wager no such usage panel has been subjected to 'After this examination, my advisor suggested that Betty be to find a new teacher.'

@EdwinAshworth It is not intended to be so. It was meant to encapsulate the idea that the sentence combines individually grammatical concepts that put together become unidiomatic. But I suspect that your contention comes more from a difference in the definition of grammaticality, namely whether something is grammatical because it feels grammatical to a native speaker or because it is composed according to a set of logical understandings about the language in question. In this case, the use veered more towards the latter.


??After this examination, my advisor suggested that Betty be to find a new teacher.

Right off the bat, the construction feels extremely awkward in that the alleged subjective be is redundant, as the same meaning can be conveyed without the ‘be to + infinitive’ structure:

After this examination, my advisor suggested that Betty find a new teacher.

What meaning does the original sentence convey that the shorter sentence doesn't? None.
Theoretically, it's obvious why the ‘be to + infinitive’ structure is redundant in the present subjunctive. Both the ‘be to + infinitive’ structure and the present subjunctive have some sort of modality meaning, so their modal meanings overlap. And this is why we don't usually use the ‘be to + infinitive’ structure after a modal:

??Betty should be to find a new teacher.

In British English, modal should is more productive than the subjunctive, so the BE version of the original should be:

??After this examination, my advisor suggested that Betty should be to find a new teacher.

Which is just as awkward.
Also, the ‘be to + infinitive’ structure cannot normally come after non-modal auxiliaries or as a non-finite clause:

??Betty has been to find a new teacher. 
??Betty was supposed to be to find a new teacher.
??Betty kept being to find a new teacher.


To put the final point more bluntly, the [be to + infinitive] construction is only ever found in the simple present and past tenses. ‘She is/was to find a new teacher’ is fine; every other permutation just isn’t used. It essentially works like a modal verb in having finite forms only.

@JanusBahsJacquet Yes that's exactly what I'm saying, albeit less bluntly.
